# How to unmarshal array in POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, go

I am trying to make a `POST` request to an API server and I am sending an array of JSON, the problem is that I get this error:

```
cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type models.UserRequest
```

I tried to unmarshal it using a factory and then initializing the objects, but I still get this error, how can I fix this error and make my request? Here is my code:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import xlsx from 'xlsx';
const baseUrl = "";
const apiToken = "";
const accountId = "";
const wb = xlsx.readFile('users.xlsx');
const ws = wb.Sheets['users'];
const data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
// console.log(data)
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${apiToken}`,
    "gtmhub-accountid": accountId,
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  },
 

  body: JSON.stringify(
    data
  ),
};


const createUser = (url, settings) => {
  return fetch(`${url}/users`, settings)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
};

createUser(baseUrl, options);
```

Comment: You should probably add a Go tag, since this is a Go error.

Comment: If sheet_to_json returns a JSON document, then use the return value directly as the request body.   Do not encode the value  to JSON a second time with json.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able, that you send right object structure to you api service. Also this seems like as the problem on the api service side

Comment: So I guess my best bet is to convert the array of json data to just json

Comment: You are already send plain json to api, it”s happens, when you calling JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: I ment to remove the array somehow, because ```xlsx``` converts the data to an array of JSON